# How to handle asp buttons in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using HTML buttons in MVC, but is there any way to handle ASP buttons in MVC rather than HTML buttons?

Answer (score 2):

No, buttons in MVC are pure html code. There is no "OnClick" event like in asp.net webforms.

There is a possibility to use asp.net webforms component in MVC (you can find some blog post if you search), but I discourage this. Stick with HTML